# Importing PDF in LateX

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages

I have include `PDF` file in `latex` but I want to know that is there any method that table of content can automatically be updated after importing the `PDF` file. I searched a lot but can't find any thing useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `addtotoc` option like this:

```
\includepdf[...,addtotoc={1,section,1,{A Title},sec.1},...]{pdffilename}
```

The syntax is `addtotoc={<page number>,<section>,<level>,<heading>,<label>}`